# Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Tags: reactjs

I am doing react-rails app. I got this strange error. Seems like it is the problem in react itself. Here is the context in which i got this error:

```
var ChronicBox = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
      return {chronics: []}
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
      $.ajax({
     // some ajax call that setsState of chronicles
      });
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="chronics">
                <ChronicsList chronics={this.state.chronics.chronicsList} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

and My ChronicsList looks like:

```
var ChronicsList = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        console.log(this.props.chronics);
        var chronics = this.props.chronics.map(function(chronic){
            return(
                <Chronic name={chronic.name}/>
            )
        });

        return(
            <ul>
                {chronics}
            </ul>
        )
    }
});
```

from logs i see this:

```
undefined
can not read property .map of undefined
Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

From these i see that initially state chronics is null, therefore .map cant be used. Then when ajax call setsState my ChronicBox re-renders and chronics contain json information as folosw:

```
{
    "chronicsList": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "some allergy",
        "patient_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2016-02-11T19:05:33.434Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-02-11T19:05:33.434Z"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "one more allergy",
        "patient_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2016-02-11T19:06:04.384Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-02-11T19:06:04.384Z"
    }],
}
```

So chronics are defined now in ChronicForm. But I do not see those logs for props.chronics inside ChronicForm instead i got error:

```
Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

Is there any way to resolve this problem? I saw it was an issue in react, but it was closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you noted, `this.props.chronics` is null, and so map won't work. And so, react is unable to render your component. When data reloads and `chronics` is an array, react is able to call the render method successfully this time; but when it tries to compare the current virtual DOM tree to the previous one, it fails there as it is unable to find the previous DOM tree.

The solution is to pass an array on the initial load. So, you would have to set the initial state of your root component to:

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    chronics: {
      chronicsList: []
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you get this error generically when any component's render function throws an error. Fix the `.map` error and this error will likely disappear.

You can fix the `.map` problem with a default prop:

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
  return {
    chronics: []
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to render `null` in a ternary operation. Rendering an empty string solved the problem:

```
{this.props.list.map((n) => {
    return <option value={n.key} key={n.key}>
               {n.title}{n.isDraft ? ' - (draft)' : null}
           </option>;
    })
}
```